# How to connect atlas mongodb via ssh. uri is mongodb+srv

Tags: mongodb, go, nginx, ssh, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect mongodb which is on Atlas via ssh.

**Explanation:**

I have db hosted on Mongodb Atlas and i got uri like this

```
mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0.something.mongodb.net/
```

I have Ubuntu machine which, I can access via ssh for example IP is 111.111.111.111 so i added this IP to Atlas Network Access then, I checked if it was connecting from Ubuntu using
`mongosh` cmd and it's able to connect.

so in my local Mac, I am trying to connect mongodb for the development via ssh so it's not be able to connect. i tried few method but none is working.

1. Using SSH Tunneling. (not working.)

   `ssh -L 27030:cluster0.something.mongodb.net:27017 -p 22 user@111.111.111.111`

   In MongoDB Compass trying to connect with the uri:

   `mongodb://mongo_user:mongo_pass@localhost:27030/?authSource=admin`

   **Error**

   `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: No address associated with hostname`
2. Reverse Proxy using golang and nginx program (not working)

2.1 golang

```
func main() {
    mongoURI := "mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0.something.mongodb.net/"
    sshHost := "111.111.111.111"
    sshPort := "22"
    sshUser := "user"
    sshPass := "pass"

    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: *sshUser,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(*sshPass),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    sshClient, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v", sshHost, sshPort), sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to dial SSH: %v", err)
    }
    defer sshClient.Close()

    mongoOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI)

    listener, err := sshClient.Listen("tcp", "localhost:27030")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create SSH tunnel: %v", err)
    }
    defer listener.Close()

    mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(nil, mongoOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to MongoDB: %v", err)
    }
    defer mongoClient.Disconnect(nil)

    fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB over SSH")
}
```

2.1 nginx

```
Add the below code above http block in nginx config file 
(eg: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf for Ubuntu)

stream {
    server {
        listen  27030;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass    stream_mongo_backend;
    }

    upstream stream_mongo_backend {
        server cluster0.something.mongodb.net:27017;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just add _"local Mac"_ IP address to _"Atlas Network Access"_?

Comment: `local mac` does not have the static IP and sometimes the connection is not private due to ISP. can't help with that. and it's not that, I haven't tried it, I added my IP before but it's not connecting.